# How to access array inside Data Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to access array with the name `remedies_list` but it's returning null in console.

I tried `console.log(data.remedies_list);` but it returned NULL. How can i access the values of this remedies_list array.

[image: console snap of returned data]

On success code:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `data` doesn't seem to be the name of the actual property that's been logged. Use it like: `actualProp.data.remedies_list`

Comment: `data` is itself a child of the returned object, try `data.data.remedies_list`...

Comment: If my eyes don't deceive me, your `data` object has a `data` object of its own, of which `remedies_list` is a property. You may want `data.data.remedies_list`.

Comment: @TylerRoper tried but it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: That's not possible. At least not _in_ the `success` handler

Comment: @Andreas so what's the alternative solution. How can i move forward? Thanks

Comment: I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uazm9hf6/) to demonstrate what I'm seeing. The console screenshot you've included seems to be identical to the object structure I've defined.

Comment: From the screenshots the solution is what Tyler has already written. If this doesn't work for you, you will have to add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: What do you get if you try the following; should show you the structure of the object
alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: @TylerRoper why it's not working! Am i trying wrong syntax? https://imgur.com/9oJoYUF

Comment: @Imaduddin `data` is scoped to your `success` function, not globally. You can't access it from the console.

Comment: @Imaduddin Please put the suggested `data.data.remedies_list` *in the code itself* rather than in the console, and let us know if that works.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks it worked in code :) The issue was that i was accessing it in console directly. And yes it worked onSuccess!